# Replacing text with <span> using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to replace each word in the textarea by a span with unique id. I need the code in JavaScript. I have tried creating a DOM element and inserting it in text area using the following code.

```
var s = document.createElement('span');
var text=document.createTextNode("inside tag");
s.appendChild(text);                
document.getElementById("t1").appendChild(s);
```

t1 is the is the id of my text area. The above code isn't giving any result.

Also, I tried another method:

```
document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML="<span>inside tag</span>";
```

`innerHTML` isn't working here.

What do I do?

Comment: `document.getElementById("t1").value="<span>inside tag</span>";`

Comment: yeah. Thats what i used. But that also isn't working.

Comment: A `<textarea>` doesn't normally allow for child elements. Only text content (its `value`). The one exception is if it's set to be [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable).

Comment: @HarshitaLal Then create a minimal example so we can see what you have, because using just `.value` should work.

Comment: @RohitAzad: Please don't put random words in backquotes. It makes it harder to read.

Comment: @ruakh Are you meaning to the OP (*@HarshitaLal*) about the `isn't`?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: The OP isn't who put the `isn't` in backquotes. See http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33820393/revisions.

Comment: @ruakh Oh, didn't notice that. Wasn't thinking someone would do that in an edit. They must of meant to do that to the `innerHTML`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek using .value prints "<span>inside tag</span>" as a string into the textarea rather than creating a span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be the **value** property instead of the **innerHtml** because of the fact that **value** property is used for setting the value  for input/form elements. **innerHTML** on the other hand is normally used for div, span, td and similar elements.

So as you are using a textarea you shall go with value property.

```
document.getElementById("t1").value = "Whatever the text/html you want to insert here";
```

Comment: using .value prints "<span>inside tag</span>" as a string into the textarea rather than creating a span.

Comment: @HarshitaLal If you are trying to embed pure html within textarea the answer is no. It's not possible to create a span tag within textarea you can enter the HTML in string fromat only. The HTML <textarea> element represents a multi-line plain-text editing control.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was of great help.

Comment: @HarshitaLal You are welcome. You can mark this answer as the answer by clicking on it if it was of any help. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To change your `value` of text arena, you will have to do this:

```
document.getElementById('t1').value = '<span>inside tag</span>';
```